# Is C++ conform and How to delete widget from a signal

Tags: c++, frame

I came across a basic question in writing a GUI in C++.

When a button is clicked, it should delete its parent frame, and so itself.
But the signal/slot mechanism causes obviously a segmentation fault when the button is deleted.

When no signal is used, the code below simulates a similar behaviour.
a is created with a child b. b is asked to be deleted (similar to click the button).

This compiles and run without any error with valgrind.

header .h

```
class B;

class A {
  private:
  B* fB;

  public:
  A();
  B* GetB() {return fB;}
  void DeleteB();
};

class B {
  private:
  A* parent;

  public:
  B(A* a) {parent = a;}
  void DeleteMyself();
};
```

implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test_delete.h"

A::A() {
  std::cout << "Constructor A" << std::endl;
  fB = new B( this );
}

void A::DeleteB() {
  std::cout << "DeleteB " << std::endl;
  if (fB != 0) {
    std::cout << "delete fB " << std::endl;
    delete fB;
    fB = 0;
  } else {
    std::cout << "fB is already null" << std::endl;
  }
}

void B::DeleteMyself() {
  std::cout << "B::DeleteMyself" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "this " << this << std::endl;
  parent->DeleteB();

  // this is printed after object is deleted
  std::cout << "B::DeleteMyself after DeleteB" << std::endl;
  // this has the same value
  std::cout << "this " << this << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {

  // creates container A and child B
  A * a = new A();
  b = a->GetB();
  // b will ask to its parent to be killed
  b->DeleteMyself();

  delete a;
}
```

So I have 2 questions:

- Is this code really valid ? It seems strange to be in a function of B once the object has been deleted.
- What is the best way to implement the delete button in a GUI ?

There are 2 solutions I can think of:

- Rewrite the GUI to have a separate frame for deleting the object (like a separate list, independent of the frame to delete). But it looks graphically intuitive like it is now. I have many b's, each with their own delete button.
- One suggested me to use some timer. Setting a flag, and call a function to delete all childs flagged after maybe 1 second. The signal terminated and the object are correctly deleted. I tested and seems working. But this design seems more a trick.

I am using a very specific GUI library, ROOT (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/).
Maybe the limitation is due to this framework, but I do not think so.

I tried to be clear,
Thanks in advance for your advices,
Michael

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "signal/slot mechanism"?

Comment: It a mechanism similar in ROOT and in Qt. A button emit a click(the signal), and one of my method is associated to it(the slot). The signal is still leaving when the button is deleted and so error segmentation

Answer (score 5):

Deleting an object inside one of its methods is ok, provided you don't reference any attribute after the operation in the rest of method code.

The problem in GUI is however solved normally by simply "marking for deletion" the widget and having the deletion handled in the main event loop. See for example the [`deleteLater`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) call of Qt library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I will go for the timer (handled by the main loop also in ROOT I think) or try to implement a simple garbage collector than I can run from time to time.